# How to retrieve only columns which have at least one not null value in any row in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have table structure and data as below
 https://ibb.co/mkGp67

I want a SQL Query to retrieve data only for those columns which have at least one not null value in it, in above case i want data comes out to be

https://ibb.co/mz9967

i.e. i don't need column Col2, Col5 and Col6, also which column having all null value is not fixed.

Please let me know the SQL query which retreive data that having only those column which having not null value with data as above.

Comment: No Images for sample data please..Only in text format. Also, post the query that you have tried.

Comment: i m trying to load images but not able to load

Comment: Please don't post links to unknown pages. Edit your question and paste the text into the question, [formatting it as needed](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Thanks.

Comment: What Kaushik Nayak meant is that you should **not** be using images at all, but posting data as text, e.g. by providing CREATE TABLE & INSERT statements, or by using code formatting and drawing the table ASCII-style.

Answer (score 0):

As far, as I know, you will not be able to achieve this with an SQL query. One of the strong assumptions of SELECT statements is that the list of returned columns is static - defined in the query, not by the data. Even for PIVOT queries (available - as far, as I know - since Oracle 11), the list of columns is defined in the query, by providing a list of values to be converted to columns has to be explicitly given.

What you are looking for is some kind of code, dynamically generating the query. This can be PL/SQL, returning cursor references or any application code.

**Edit:**

What you could do with a query, is to have a clear information on which columns do contain nulls, which do not, etc. It could look something like this:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 'no rows'
         WHEN COUNT(Col1) = 0 THEN 'all NULLs'
         WHEN COUNT(Col1) = COUNT(*) THEN 'no NULLs'
         ELSE 'some NULLs'
       END Col1NullStatus,
       CASE
         WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 'no rows'
         WHEN COUNT(Col2) = 0 THEN 'all NULLs'
         WHEN COUNT(Col2) = COUNT(*) THEN 'no NULLs'
         ELSE 'some NULLs'
       END Col2NullStatus,
       CASE
         WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 'no rows'
         WHEN COUNT(Col3) = 0 THEN 'all NULLs'
         WHEN COUNT(Col3) = COUNT(*) THEN 'no NULLs'
         ELSE 'some NULLs'
       END Col3NullStatus,
       CASE
         WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 'no rows'
         WHEN COUNT(Col4) = 0 THEN 'all NULLs'
         WHEN COUNT(Col4) = COUNT(*) THEN 'no NULLs'
         ELSE 'some NULLs'
       END Col4NullStatus,
       CASE
         WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 'no rows'
         WHEN COUNT(Col5) = 0 THEN 'all NULLs'
         WHEN COUNT(Col5) = COUNT(*) THEN 'no NULLs'
         ELSE 'some NULLs'
       END Col5NullStatus,
       CASE
         WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 'no rows'
         WHEN COUNT(Col6) = 0 THEN 'all NULLs'
         WHEN COUNT(Col6) = COUNT(*) THEN 'no NULLs'
         ELSE 'some NULLs'
       END Col6NullStatus
  FROM myTable
```

See [SQL Fiddle for the above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93536e/4).

**Edit 2:**

And the output of this query would look something like this:

```
Col1NullStatus | Col2NullStatus | Col3NullStatus | Col4NullStatus | Col5NullStatus | Col6NullStatus
---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------
no NULLs       | all NULLs      | some NULLs     | no NULLs       | all NULLs      | all NULLs
```

This is the format, you could be using, to post your input data and expected results.

Comment: How does this comment relate to the answer?

Comment: thank u very much Mr Hilarion i want to display only no nulls and some nulls column and hide all nulls column

Comment: @zahidgs: As I wrote in the answer, I do not see it as possible using just an SQL query. You could use the query I've given in the answer in your application code (or in PL/SQL) to dynamically build a query, which only has the columns matching your criteria.

Comment: @zahidgs: Again, the StackOverflow rules of asking the questions and providing answers, is to have the necessary information here, on StackOverflow, not in external services. Those can still be referenced as additional help, to back up any claims, etc. We've already shown you how you can post the data here and I've already told you, that what you are asking about does not seem to be doable by one single static SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

So, since you give no no formal table structure, and you seem to be confusing numbers and chars(s), I will do my best to try and make a query that will at least produce the results you want.

create table foo as (
col1 varchar(10),
col2 varchar(10),
col3 varchar(10),
col4 varchar(10),
col5 varchar(10),
col6 varchar(10)
);

select * 
   CASE cust1 WHEN null then 'null' else cust1 as cust1 end,
   CASE cust2 WHEN null then 'null' else cust1 as cust1 end,
   CASE cust3 WHEN null then 'null' else cust1 as cust1 end,
   CASE cust4 WHEN null then 'null' else cust1 as cust1 end,
   CASE cust5 WHEN null then 'null' else cust1 as cust1 end,
   CASE cust6 WHEN null then 'null' else cust1 as cust1 end
from foo ;

Answer (score 0):

```
As per below query , I able to get not null columns at row-level col1,col3 and col4.

Query :
select 'col1' as "Name",col1 from temp
 where  exists (select  1 
 from temp
 group by to_char(col1)
 having (count(to_char(col1)))> 0)
 union all 
 select 'col2' as "Name",to_char(col2) from temp
 where  exists (select  1 
 from temp
 group by to_char(col2)
 having (count(to_char(col2)))> 0)
 union all
 select 'col3' as "Name" , to_char(col3) from temp
 where  exists (select  1 
 from temp
 group by to_char(col3)
 having (count(to_char(col3)))> 0)
 union all
 select 'col4'as "Name" , to_char(col4) from temp
 where  exists (select  1 
 from temp
 group by to_char(col4)
 having (count(to_char(col4)))> 0)
 union all
 select 'col5' as "Name" , to_char(col5) from temp
 where  exists (select  1 
 from temp
 group by to_char(col5)
 having (count(to_char(col5)))> 0)
 union all
 select 'col6' as "Name" , to_char(col6) from temp
 where  exists (select  1 
 from temp
 group by to_char(col6)
 having (count(to_char(col6)))> 0)

output:

col1    A
col1    B
col1    C
col1    D
col3    10
col3    20
col3     - 
col3    10
col4    12
col4    23
col4    34
col4    43

I tried to make this output of rows to columns but I couldn't make it in single query ... Hope this will be helpful ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this usually in three steps.

Firstly, make sure that the table statistics are up to date. Check if `last_analyzed` is later than the last change to the table.

```
SELECT last_analyzed FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE';
```

If in doubt, update the statistics with

```
BEGIN dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('MYSCHEMA','MYTABLE'); END;
/
```

Now, the view `user_tab_columns` has a column `num_nulls`. This is the number of rows where this column is `NULL`. If the value is the same than the number of rows in the table, all rows are `NULL`. This can be used to let Oracle generate the required SQL:

```
WITH 
  qtab AS (SELECT owner, table_name, num_rows
             FROM all_tables 
            WHERE owner='SCOTT'            -- change to your schema
              AND table_name='EMPLOYEES'   -- change to your table name
           ),
  qcol AS (SELECT owner, table_name, column_name, column_id
             FROM qtab t 
             JOIN all_tab_columns c USING (owner, table_name)
            WHERE c.nullable = 'N'         -- protected by NOT NULL constraint 
               OR c.num_nulls = 0          -- never NULL
               OR c.num_nulls < t.num_rows -- at least 1 row is NOT NULL
              )  
              )  
SELECT 'SELECT '||LISTAGG(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_id)||
        ' FROM '||owner||'.'||table_name||';' AS my_query
  FROM qcol
 GROUP BY owner, table_name;
```

This will output a query like

```
SELECT col1, col3, col4, col5 FROM myschema.mytable;
```

This query can now be executed to show the column values.